# How to use Format files in SSIS Data Flow task?

Tags: ssis, format

I am able to migrate data between two SQL Server tables easily using a SSIS data flow task. Can I use format files to specify the columns to choose from the source and destination? If so, can you give me an example?

In our current system, our Source and Destination tables are always not the same. We were using SQL-DMO with format files so far and are now upgrading to SSIS.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: An ssis dataflow task would not use format files, but a bulk insert task would.  Are you asking how to use a format file with a bulk insert task?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I think that answers my question. I can try using Bulk Insert with Format files but if you have any link handy on how to do that, please do let me know. Is there a way to export using Format files in SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that you can look up info on how to create a format file here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx
Google SSIS Bulk Insert Task to find more on that.

I would recommend using a data flow if you can because this can eliminate columns from the source that do not exist in the destination and it can out perform bulk inserts.  It's worth consideration.

Mark

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do the Bulk Insert using format files. The reason why we wanted to use format files is  1) Our source and dest table structures are many times different and 2) we want to avoid modifying the packages and instead modify the format files. Any thoughts on exporting leveraging SSIS other than exporting a custom view?

Comment: I would try not to make a one size fits all solution. Sure table structures change between environments, but is that what usually happens?  Are there a certain set of tables that need special handling and the rest are stable and you can use an ssis df?  For those special cases use the format file approach, but for the other 90%, don't fuss with all that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post to which I just finished answering my own question and thought will link the two posts together.

[SSIS - Export multiple SQL Server tables to multiple text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302633/ssis-export-multiple-sql-server-tables-to-multiple-text-files)